# Piece of gear vs. article of gear

Tags: grammatical-number

What is correct (or are both expressions correct):

1. Piece of gear
2. Article of gear

I learned that if there is no specific singular of a word I have to use `piece of ...` but when I look into some dictionarries I see the `article of gear` although I find `piece of gear` a lot on websites (just by googling for that expression).

So what's the correct one or are both correct and if yes in which cases I use the one or the other?

Comment: This is the case where 1 works: When my trash compactor broke last year, I had to extract a piece of gear from the back of the cabinet.

Comment: I mean with `gear` the same as `equipment`. I think you refer to the mechanical "gear" right?

Comment: I would say that "piece of gear" is more idiomatic in the US.  "Article of gear" sounds a hair confused, since "article" is formal and "gear" is informal.  (Though even "piece of equipment" is more idiomatic than "article..." in the US.)

Comment: Neither sounds great to me. When talking about a collection of related items I might say "gear" but when talking about a single piece, I'd just call it what it is. Instead of "piece of gear" just say "shoe" or "carabiner" or "sleeping bag" or whatever it was.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases sound wrong to my ears to be honest, for the simple reason that I've never heard them being used before. I would be more inclined to use "an item of gear".

Example: "An item of gear has been stolen from the boat".

Bear in mind though that just because my Irish ears think that "piece of gear" is wrong, doesn't mean that it is not perfectly acceptable elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Both are incorrect because "gear" is uncountable.  We use "some" for gear, so "some gear." or to use the example from the other answer, "Some gear was stolen from the boat."

Article is used for clothing, as in "an article of clothing."  We also use "some" for clothing, "take some clothing with you."

Comment: Okay so it's `a piece of equipment`, `an article of clothing` but `some gear` right? Sounds strange to me but I'm not a native speaker (as you may guess). What about the proposal of @Baz with `an item of gear`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "piece of gear", other than the informality of "gear".  "Equipment" is just as "uncountable" as "gear" in this context.

Comment: @HotLicks since when did gear or equipment become formal or informal words?  The business English book that I was using this evening (Oxford UP) teaches equipment as uncountable...we were talking about this very subject in class tonight.  I feel it is incorrect to use piece with equipment...piece of bread is acceptable...but not gear or equipment...piece of what?  Equipment is a collection of things...say exactly what...a hammer, a wrench, a sonic screwdriver.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I feel that piece of equipment is also incorrect.

Comment: How is a piece of bread different from a piece of equipment (I mean linguistically, not considering that you can eat one and not the other)?

Comment: @HotLicks I realize I'm in the minority on this because the Internet and MacMillan say I'm wrong.  I feel that bread, cheese, cake, music, and other things in that category are not comprised of a collection of objects and that if you slice off a piece of cake it is indistinguishable from the larger piece (aside from being smaller).  Gear and equipment consist of a group of objects that are all different, so if I remove a hammer from someone's equipment it doesn't represent the whole--you can't look at it and guess what the other parts are or what the collection looks like as a whole.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - So if I remove a blueberry from the bagel I buy every morning, that's not a "piece" of the bagel?

Comment: @HotLicks If I can't see the bagel, how do I know the blueberry came from it?  Cake is obvious.  What if I found a hair in my soup?  Is that part or piece of the soup?  I'm fine with others saying piece of equipment and article of gear.  Heck, we might as well throw away all counters because we can rationalize them into oblivion.  "Waiter, I spilled some pieces of water on my pants." or "I listened to three musics yesterday while having two cakes."

Comment: @HotLicks I think the blueberry is funny...reminds me of the scene in Casino in which Ace tells the chef that each muffin must have an equal number of blueberries.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - I have to agree with Hot that *gear* is uncountable.  A noun doesn't have to be homogeneous to be uncountable.  But if you'd like to see what the general consensus is, you could write a Question.

Comment: @aparente001 But I agree that gear is uncountable.  I just feel that some should be the counter, not piece or article.

Comment: The only way a piece, item, or other unit of gear seems appropriate to me is when you know the item is from a set or collection, but you don't know its specific nature. Like if you see a bunch of camping equipment in the back of my truck, and one random piece falls out, but you aren't sure exactly what it was.

Comment: @barbecue maybe it's better to use "item" for equipment.  In your example, "...and one random item falls out."

Comment: @michael_timoffev: If I ask to borrow a *"piece of paper"* from somebody, they generally do not tear a sheet of paper in half before they give it to me. If I ask for a *"piece of fruit"*, do I get half an apple? When musicians play a *"piece of music"*, they usually play an entire song and not half of it. And there is a difference between a *"piece of apparatus"* and a *"piece of an apparatus"*. This idea you have that a *"piece"* of something uncountable has to be part of a larger whole is total nonsense.

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe people used to say "sheet" for paper.  I'm not saying it has to be part of the original I'm saying it has to be indistinguishable (in some cases) or look like it.  Unfortunately, it seems that this is also on a case by case logic, so my reasoning for gear and equipment falls apart for other uses.  In the books I use for my classes, equipment and gear are uncountable and take "some" and most of my students who were exposed to this remember being taught this in high school.

Comment: @Michael: *some* is perfectly fine for *equipment, machinery*, and *gear,* but so is *piece*.

Comment: @PeterShor if there is a bowl of fruit containing apples, oranges, pears, etc, does someone say "Can I have a piece of fruit?" or would they say "Can I have an apple?"  Is fruit countable or uncountable?  Perhaps with counters, there are generalities and then case by case exceptions.  As a teacher, my question is, "how do I approach this if everything has an exception or depends on the mood or education of the speaker?"  What I usually say now is, "you will hear people say it this way, however if you use what we learned in class, people will understand you always."

Comment: You would probably ask *"can I have an apple?"* But you would probably offer one by saying *"would you like a piece of fruit?"* And not *"would you like an orange, apple, pear, peach, apricot or plum?"*

Comment: @PeterShor what makes this difficult to discuss is that unlike other disciplines, we don't have data to back this up, so to me, "would you like a piece of fruit." isn't what I would say but maybe everyone in the Midwest and also Australia says that, so it is "correct" at some level.  I don't trust Google anymore because Google is now filled with millions of non native speakers writing articles, most of which are riddled with errors...Google books may be better.